# Swipe to see options in iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

How can I implement swipe to see more options? There are lot of [libraries](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell) that I could readily use, but they all are designed for iPhone apps. In iPad you have a lot of space, and I want to stack the buttons vertically instead of horizontally.

Is there any library for this? If not, how should I go about building this as a custom cell?

I tried building a custom `UITableViewCell` class which adds a `UIScrollView`, but it's not the same as showing the buttons beneath the cell.

Comment: I bet at least one of these libraries would let you supply a custom view for your buttons with them aligned vertically. Alternatively, you could modify one of the many existing libraries, or make your own from scratch.

Comment: Can you describe more fully what you want? What should the animation look like? Since you want the buttons stacked vertically, do you want the swipe to be down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your inputs I have created a simple custom cell with basic functionality of swipe to see utility buttons and of course buttons stacked vertically.

What I did was, add a UIView beneath the cell's content view and positioned at right. Now depending on the number of buttons provided each button's height is adjusted accordingly. And delegates are provided for button clicks.

Swipe gestures are added. On swiping left it will animate and shift the cell's content view to reveal the button view. On swiping right it will reset the cell to original position.

You can customise it from here onwards as you wish :)

I have uploaded them over here : https://github.com/srikanth-vm/GSSwipeableCell